# Magento2 : How to Move Pinterest Button in Product Image in Product Page

Tags: magento2, product, product-images

How to move `pinterest(pin it)` button in product image in product view page. Currently it is coming after add to cart button.

How to change `pinterest(pin it)` button to product image section.

Comment: please send me screenshot where u exact want?

Comment: in product image like product badge